# Task Schedular Running Fails #Permission?

Tags: windows, permissions, task, server, scheduler

I have some really strange phenomena appearing on my PC, using Task Schedular.

We created a normal Task which is triggered every morning at 7 o'clock.
The interesting part is, that the history of Task Scheduler says, that it was running successfully.

But it didn't work.

I then created 2 other Scripts.
The first script is starting calc.
The second script creates a folder in c:/Temp

When starting those scripts over Explorer everything is running as expected.

But when running those scripts over task scheduler only the calc is starting and there won't be any folder in c:/Temp.

I already created a policy report, but nothing configured in the category Task Scheduler.

By the way the account configured in the Task Scheduler has local Admin right and run as batch job rights.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code of your script? It's hard to guess why it's not working without knowing what it does. Btw. as you are on Windows it's C:\Temp and not C:/Temp ;-)

Comment: 1st Skript: start calc
2nd Skript: 
echo test > C:\temp\log.txt
mkdir C:\temp\test
pause

I see script is starting, but there is no Logfile. 

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that the folder C:\Temp does exist, right?

Comment: When starting those scripts over Explorer everything is running as expected.

But when running those scripts over task scheduler only the calc is starting and there won't be any folder in c:\Temp

And yes c:\Temp does exist.

Comment: Although you've said that you are using an account with local admin rights it still seems that the script doesnt have write permission to C:\Temp. Is it possible that the credentials in the scheduler are wrong?

Comment: I also think that the Scipt doesn't have permission to do things, Even though, the account is member of local Administrators

Comment: Have you checkde the "run with highest priority option"?

Comment: Yes I did! And I think I just found the solution.

Script 1 creats a folder with timestamp in the name.
The script is in c:\Temp but the folder is created in c:\Windows\system32 (where cmd.exe is situated)

I now rewrite relative paths to absolute paths.

Comment: Omg...could have told you that. And that's why I've asked for the code... :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check any dependent files and permissions:

If permissions or ownership of a file changes that your task managed script depends on or uses (not necessary the one IN YOUR TASK), you need to make sure you re-sync your task to recognize those changes.

(for instance, if you've changed any permissions to C:\Temp but HAVEN'T resaved your Task...)

I've had the steps below fix issues when a script would run fine by itself, but after some change to it or a dependent file, would no longer run properly from Task Scheduler.

1) Open task schedular
2) find and double-click the troubled task like your going to edit it
3) Hit 'Ok'. 
4) When prompted, enter credentials to save it. (If your credentials don't work then update them...that is a different problem)
5) try to re-run task from scheduler (r-click -> Run) then see if it works correctly.

NOTE: Just because the task successfully runs does NOT mean your script worked as it should. Check yourself to make sure the log file you want WAS created.